# Sharepoint online Auto-generating number starting in 6000's

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, microsoft-flow, auto-increment

I am looking for help with my power apps / SharePoint online solution I am building. I created a canvas app from a SharePoint list. I need to figure out how to create an auto generating unique id.

The numbers need to match their current numbering system, which starts in the 6000's. I have a deadline of Friday 10/4.

Comment: hi ! So if your looking for this, why dont you do a quick FLOW which adds a new item to the list, and then removes it. then run it 6k times. then the column will start at 6,000

Comment: then of course, all new items will start at 6,000 and carry on.. Or you can create a new ID column and initalise it 6,000 and increment as you go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Built-in ID column and a flow to do the unique id work for the list. Here is a sample flow. It will automatically generate the ID for new Item. You can see the demo below. 
[image]

[image]

For existing items, please try the following flow. 
[image]